# "...and say something like "touch base," "engagement targets," or "content node."" what is implied here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Offices can be pretty stressful. It might all seem fine, but at any moment, someone could walk up to you and say something like **"touch base,"** **"engagement targets,"** or **"content node."** All of a sudden your brow is furrowed, and beads of sweat form as you expend previously unimaginable amounts of energy attempting to turn yourself into a human fireball of rage and indignation (and fire).

From: [Where Is My Hammer? is a free game about destruction (PC Gamer)](http://www.pcgamer.com/where-is-my-hammer-is-a-free-game-about-destruction/)

I don't know what these expressions in bold mean, and why they would make someone angry. It looks like "to touch base" is "to contact someone" and "content node" is some kind of an IT term, but I'm not sure. What "engagement targets" mean I can only guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, when you're working in a (stereotypical) corporate environment, the presence of so-called 'buzzwords' in conversation is not good news. It means that the person talking to you is likely to a) not have any idea what they are talking about, b) be in management (or wishing to be) and c) be about to waste your time with a useless conversation or unenjoyable task.

Much like Pavlov's Dog, office workers the world over have learned to associate the presence of words and phrases like the ones mentioned with irritating, pointless people, often given far more power than they are really equipped to handle. So in this scenario, the person walking up and saying something like "We need to touch base on the engagement targets of your content nodes" triggers an angry response.

In the real world, that response is usually confined to mentally wishing all sorts of misfortune upon the speaker, but based on the title of the game it seems to have escalated to 'Good lord, I am going to beat this useless waste of space with a hammer.'

Thankfully, I haven't run into 'engagement targets' or 'content node' before, but at a guess I'd say the former is dealing with user engagement ("We need 90% satisfaction and 75% conversion") and the latter is just a fancy way of saying 'product'.

Comment: This web page is a "content node".  A content node is a place (aka "node") in a web (aka "graph") that contains stuff ("content") that someone might find useful.  A "content node" can be contrasted with an index, a table of contents, an advertisement, a "splash screen" (aka "interstitial"), or other "non-content node".  "Nodes" are places in the "graph"; "links" are connections between "nodes".

Comment: I think you've nailed it on the source of the rage. It's not the buzzwords themselves that turn workers into a fireball of indignation, it's the phenomenon of using buzzwords to sound intelligent when in reality they only emphasize how ignorant the speaker is already perceived. Of course, instead of getting angry, you can always play [Buzzword Bingo](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BuzzwordBingo). _When life gives you lemons..._